# Sorting an ObservableCollection partially while preserving the order for some as given

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to sort an ObservableCollection that has items that must be sorted partially by name on some and preserve the sort as the data is already given from it source.

The data comes to me as:

The result of the above will print as below:

```
First Item
A Second Item
Third Item
Item 1
Item 10
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
Item 7
Item 8
Item 9
```

Here is the collection sample to generate the above data (This is just a sample I created to give me data like above):

```
ObservableCollection<MyObject> items = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();

items.Add(new MyObject { ItemID = 1, Name = "First Item", Category = "0" });
items.Add(new MyObject { ItemID = 2, Name = "A Second Item", Category = "0" });
items.Add(new MyObject { ItemID = 3, Name = "Third Item", Category = "0" });
items.Add(new MyObject { ItemID = 4, Name = "Item 1", Category = "1" });
items.Add(new MyObject { ItemID = 13, Name = "Item 10", Category = "1" });
items.Add(new MyObject { ItemID = 5, Name = "Item 2", Category = "1" });
items.Add(new MyObject { ItemID = 6, Name = "Item 3", Category = "1" });
items.Add(new MyObject { ItemID = 7, Name = "Item 4", Category = "1" });
items.Add(new MyObject { ItemID = 8, Name = "Item 5", Category = "1" });
items.Add(new MyObject { ItemID = 9, Name = "Item 6", Category = "1" });
items.Add(new MyObject { ItemID = 10, Name = "Item 7", Category = "1" });
items.Add(new MyObject { ItemID = 11, Name = "Item 8", Category = "1" });
items.Add(new MyObject { ItemID = 12, Name = "Item 9", Category = "1" });


foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Here is my MyObject

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want the above to be sorted as:

```
First Item // This must be preserved like this
A Second Item // This must be preserved like this
Third Item // This must be preserved like this
Item 1 // Rest below must be sorted like below and not Item 1, Item 11...
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
Item 7
Item 8
Item 9
Item 10
```

If I use, `var sorted = items.OrderBy(x => x.Name)` I don't get the result what I want.
How can I get the sorting be done only on partial items?

Based on the comment. I cant rely on the ItemID. It is not reliable.
The only piece I can rely to sort in the name and category.

This is my final solution I did:

```
    Func<string, object> convert = str =>
        {
            int k;
            if (int.TryParse(str, out k))
                return k;
            return str;
        };


        var sorted = items.Where(x => x.Category != "1").Union(items.Where(x => x.Category == "1")
            .OrderBy(str => Regex.Split(str.Name.Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)").Select(convert),
            new EnumerableComparer<object>()));

        foreach (var item in sorted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }
```

I used Tim. S's link for implementing the natural sort comparer with Badak's idea.

Comment: just **orderby(X=>X.ItemID)**

Comment: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting has a good C# solution for 'natural' sorting.

Comment: ID is not reliable. I should made it clear. I updated my post since.

Comment: @Tim: link in your comment will address my Item 1, Item 10 issue. But how do I do it only for part of the items?

Comment: Hm..I think you could implement a comparator that takes the category into account, so that e.g. all cat "0" items are equal to each other, and smaller than all cat "1" items (or more generally, if it looks like the `Name` doesn't have a number like that, it retains the order by comparing only the categories).

Comment: You are correct. Category 0 will not have number in it's name and must preserve order. Category 1 will have number in the name and must natural sort. I will look at the comparer approach

Comment: you mean category then name but (not item1 then item10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can distinguish items by

```
 foreach (var item in items.Where(X => !X.Name.StartsWith("Item")).Union(items.Where(X => X.Name.StartsWith("Item")).OrderBy(X => Convert.ToInt32(X.Name.Replace("Item ", "")))))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }
```

This works if and only if the the items that starts with **Item** are followed by an **int**, other elements stays above

Comment: I was able to use it without "Item" assumption but use category using Tim S is link for comparer. Here it is: items.Where(x => x.Category != "1").Union(items.Where(x => x.Category == "1")
    .OrderBy(str => Regex.Split(str.Name.Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)").Select(convert),
    new EnumerableComparer<object>()));

Comment: Only issue with this is I was getting "A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" exception. any idea?

Comment: I got it. I changed the try in this Func<string, object> convert = str =>
   {
    try { return int.Parse(str); }
    catch { return str; }
   }; to TryParse

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
///...
items.OrderBy(item=>item, comparer);
```

where comparer is a class what implements `IComparer<MyObject>`
Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549422%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I am looking into this approach now.